# When accessing 'amiunique.org/fp' using chromedriver, my user-agent is 'unique' but identical to my normal browser user agent

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, user-agent

When selenium chromedriver accesses 'amiunique.org/fp' , this is the user agent footprint:

[image]

User-agent: <0.01% of users use it (just me a few times)

However, when I use my normal browser, with an identical user agent, I get this:

[image]

user-agent 0.04%, which is relatively normal.

I am unsure why this is happening I am sure it is contributing to my constant detection.

This is the code that changes the user agent:

```
        headers = randint(0, 1)

        with open('headers.csv', 'r') as fd:

            reader = csv.reader(fd)

            reader = list(reader)

            driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {

                                    "userAgent": ''.join(reader[headers])})
```